# internal server error when I add settings of Imageresizer watermark plugin in web.config asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

When I add settings of `Imageresizer` watermark plugin I've got internal server error.I just add a text bottom of Image in the left I've added code at last of `web.config` file for example.

```
<configuration>
  <resizer>
    <watermarks>
      <text name="test2" text="store" vertical="true" align="bottomleft" />
    </watermarks>
  </resizer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've founded I have to add resizer name in configsection that's it.

```
 <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" />
```